# Как отфильтровать объект?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго вечера. Подскажите,пожалуйста, как отфильтровать объект к примеру, если по условию (если price не нуль).

```
const products{
 "72": 
{id: 72, "price": "", "weight": ""},
"71": 
{id: '71', "price": '12000', "weight": '25кг'}
}
```

Comment: *если price не* **нуль** - **нуль** это **0** или это **null**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял, вам нужно получить товары, цена которых не равна 0. Чтобы решить эту задачу, вы можете воспользоваться этим кодом

```js
function getItemsNotEqualToZero(products) {
  if (typeof products !== "object") {
    return {};
  }

  return Object
    .keys(products)
    .filter((key) => parseInt(products[key].price || 0) !== 0)
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = products[key];

      return acc;
    }, {});
}

  console.log(getItemsNotEqualToZero({
  "72": { id: 72, "price": "", "weight": "" },
  "71": { id: '71', "price": '12000', "weight": '25кг' }
}));
```

Comment: Не работает. Выдает исходный объект...

Comment: Уберите "!!" рядом с `products[key]`

Comment: Тем более, я же написал, что будет работать, если ключ `price` будет содержать цифровой тип данных

Comment: Попробуйте добавить объект: `"73": { price: null, weight: '42кг' },` (В вопросе было написано, что такие цены нужно фильтровать)

Comment: Ключ `price` не равен нулю, значит объект будет содержать данный товар. Как говорится в задаче: если price не нуль (не null, а 0)

Comment: Если убрать ключ `price`, поведение аналогино. Поправьте, что бы работало для тех типов данных, которые указаны в вопросе. Я даже когда редактировал ваш ответ ошибку допустил в нужном вам направлении

Comment: Хотя достаточно было `products[key].price !== 0` заменить на `!!products[key].price`. И раз уж вы взялись проверять на тип данных, то добавьте проверку, что это не массив `Array.isArray()`, т.к. массив тоже имеет тип 'object'

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev нуль != ноль.